# Is it safe to feed a HandlerThread with a "poison pill"?

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm trying to work out a workaround for the fact that HandlerThread's quitSafely() is available from API 18 (I'm targetting 14). I ended up with borrowing the "poison pill" concept from actor systems - a message that causes the thread to quit when it is processed. My implementation is as follows:

```
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.Looper;

public class WorkerThread extends HandlerThread {
    private Handler mWorkerHandler;

    public WorkerThread(String name) {
        super(name);
    }

    public void prepareHandler(){
        mWorkerHandler = new Handler(getLooper());
    }

    public void postTask(Runnable task){
        mWorkerHandler.post(task);
    }

    public boolean quitSafely() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
            return super.quitSafely();
        } else {
            Looper looper = getLooper();
            if (looper != null) {
                mWorkerHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        quit();
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it safe to do it like this (in terms of message processing correctness and the thread not blowing up when quit from the inside)?